# serve swagger-ui for a backend RoR application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, swagger, swagger-ui

I have a ruby on rails application which doesnot have a webserver, as it only exposes API to clients. Now, I have a swagger documentation for these apis. What are possible ways to serve the swagger ui on a url? Since there is no web server, I wanted to know if there could be other options for the same. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably know about the [rswag](https://github.com/rswag/rswag) gem, a kind of rspec-driven-swagger mechanism. Personally, I don't really like this approach, but the gem provides us with a simple translation of the url into the swagger description. Here's what you can do:

- in Gemfile

```rb
gem `rswag`
```

- in config/routes.rb

```rb
mount Rswag:: Ui:: Engine = > "/api-docs"
mount Swag::Api::Engine = >"/api-docs"
```

- creating a simple configuration config/initializers/swagger. rb

```rb
Rswag::Api.configure do |c|
  c.swagger_root = Rails.root.to_s + '/swagger'
end
Swag::Ui.configure do |c|
  c.swagger_endpoint '/api-docs/petstore.yaml', 'API V1 Docs'
end
```

- create a `swagger` directory in root of your application directory and put your API description file there (e.g. petstore. yaml)

start application and at http://localhost:3000/api-docs there will be your description

BUT

In my humble opinion, it is better to run the swagger description separately and not link the application lifecycle with public documentation. I usually publish swagger somewhere nearby with this command (or similar)

```sh
docker run --rm -it \
    -p 80:8080 \
    -v $(pwd):/swagger \
    -e SWAGGER_JSON=/swagger/swagger.yaml \
    swaggerapi/swagger-ui
```

Comment: I am using rswag gem already and the method that you descibed above works fine for me on local using http://localhost:3000/api-docs. But since there is no web server to my application, how do i access such url for stage/production environment. Do i have to setup a nginx/apache specifically for this purpose?

Comment: Swagger is accessed in the stage and production environments in a similar way - my-app.com/api-docs. No settings are required on the web server side